# TypeScript resolve exact types from json file

Tags: json, typescript, types

I have a json configuration file

```
[{ name: "apple", weight: 1.0 }, { name: "banana", weight: 2.0 }]
```

I create type that describes this configuration

```js
type Config = { name: "apple" | "banana", weight: number }[];
```

Now I create a function that returns that configuration

```js
import Configuration from './configuration.json';

function getConfig(): Config {
   return Configuration;
}
```

I get error saying that

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"apple" | "banana"'

I understand that the problem is with the field `name` which type is resolved to `string` and not `"apple" | "banana"`.

It it possible to resolve `.json` files with exact types? So that I can be sure that the `.json` file has the correct structure using only TypeScript type system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a cast problem.
Try casting it like this.

```
function getConfig(): Config {
   return Configuration as Config;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that there is no way to be sure the JSON file has the desired structure using type definitions. For example, you could change `"name": "apple"` to `"foo": "bar"` and it would still compile without an error. If you want to be 100% certain the data you're importing from a JSON file is of the desired structure, then you have to check it with actual code.